# Accessing the CancellationToken that cancelled a Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm performing the standard op of copying the result of a `Task` into a `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = ...;

Task<int> task = ...;

task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsCanceled)
        tcs.TrySetCanceled(new TaskCanceledException(task).CancellationToken);
    else if (t.IsFaulted)
        tcs.TrySetException(task.Exception.InnerExceptions);
    else
        tcs.TrySetResult(task.Result);
});
```

You might notice a funny bit of code there to set the token that triggered cancellation. This is the part I'm trying to make a little cleaner.

As an implementation detail there exists a `Task.CancellationToken` member that'd be great to have access to, but it is internal. Constructing a new `TaskCanceledException` is the cheapest way I can find to get access to it. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you do it in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you just call TrySetCanceled() without argument? TaskCompletionSource itself returns same kind of Task, which again is not able to return its cancellation token so this cancellation token is normally never accessed on the caller end. Or do I miss smth.?